# How to fix the network after ARP poisoning attack?

Tags: networking, arp

I was running a program called morpheus: https://github.com/r00t-3xp10it/morpheus.

It is a github project which allows ARP poisoning attacks, MITM attacks etc. I was running a arp spoofing/phishing attack (for the local network) and my computer reset while the program was running.

Because my computer reset without warning, the program couldn't re ARP all the  devices on the network, and therefore the entire LAN thinks that my computer is the router!

Whenever I try to visit another website on another computer it doesn't work at all and sometimes it shows my the phishing page (if I'm running the program).

Is there a way to fix the network and all the ARP tables for the devices, and if not, how long would it take for each device to fix itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question please restart all your switch(s), router/firewall and in each Windows client call **arp -d -a**

ps; Please use a lab network network next time for your test, never do that in a live environnement.

Comment: Can you please explain lab network and how to use one?